# Case Study for CMIS and Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am very new to enterprise content management concepts.

I would like to do a small hands or a case study before we embark on the full fledged thing.
My work will be mainly on the client side so I would like to get more experience in consuming server content.

For that I needed to get some experience on CMIS apis and their consumption.

I plan to develop a plain eclipse based client for the server. I would like to see the content in Eclipse RCP app.Kind of what alfresco explorer does.

I don't want install an alfresco server for myself as I would not work on the server side. How can I use an Alfresco server for my case study? Should I use the public alfresco server or the cloud based alfresco server?

Also please provide suggestions on my case study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..feeling much more enlightened after 4 hrs of CMIS and Alfresco exploration.

My query of getting a server got resolved by accessing the public cmis alfresco server which is available at http://cmis.alfresco.com/

I also downloaded [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) for windows and have setup the alfresco server locally.

Both the servers can be connected with my java client (using Apache Chemisty libs).
to connect remotely to the Alfresco server a local resovable name should be used. IP is not recognized.

One more option is to get a free trial from the alfresco cloud.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: What do you mean by "CMIS installer"? CMIS Workbench maybe?